# Hyper parameter tuning with GridsearchCV for multi output data(Neural Network) using keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, cross-validation, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I have a data which has 2 output variables and multiple input variables, I used neural network to make the model, but now I want to do hyper parameter tuning.

For tuning, I am using grid search, I wrote the code for grid search, but there is an error when I tried grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)the error is ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[ 1.62970054,  2.33817343], 
then I made 2 different arrays and then passed into the code as grid.fit(X_train, [Y[0], Y[1]), as there are 2 outputs, now its showing that ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 2]. Is there any way I can correct this code, or GridsearchCV don't accept multiple output values? I made the keras model using keras functional API and then I passed through kerasRegressor so that I can implement GridsearchCV. I am stuck at what should be the code so that grid.fit() will run...Or is there any other method by which I can do hyper parameter tuning

```py
def create_model(activation='relu', dropout_rate=0.0, neurons=10, optimizer='Adam', weight_constraint=0):
  main_input = Input(shape=(17,), name='main_input')
  hidden = Dense(neurons, activation=activation, name='hidden', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(weight_constraint))(main_input)
  hidden = Dropout(dropout_rate)(hidden)
  out1 = Dense(1,  activation='linear', name='out1')(hidden)
  out2 = Dense(1,  activation='linear',name='out2')(hidden)
  model = Model(inputs=main_input, outputs=[out1,out2])
  model.compile(optimizer = optimizer,loss={'out1':'mean_squared_error', 'out2':'mean_squared_error'})
  return model



model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, batch_size=32, epochs=100)

activation =  ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'linear'] 

dropout_rate = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
weight_constraint=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
neurons = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90]
optimizer = [ 'SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam']
epochs = [50, 100, 150, 200]
batch_size = [10, 20, 30, 40]

param_grid = dict(neurons=neurons, activation=activation, dropout_rate=dropout_rate, weight_constraint=weight_constraint, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, optimizer=optimizer)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)

grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

The error when the last line of the above code is grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train) is ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[ 1.62970054,  2.33817343],
       [ 3.44504814,  6.05534019],
       [ 1.58155862,  0.8296778 ],
       ...,
       [ 1.27446578,  6.71978433],
       [ 7.99909866, 17.82736535],
       [ 1.4...
The error when I make 2 different arrays of 2 outputs and then rewrite the last line as grid.fit(X_train, [Y[0], Y[1]) is ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10000, 2]

My data is 10000 observation with 17 input variables and 2 output variables.